# Inserting variables in mysql queries

Tags: database, function, variables, insert

I've written a function which updates the mysql database row with some new column data.
Here is the function:

```
function sql($set,$data){
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET '".$set."' = '".$data."' WHERE login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'");
    if($sql){
        echo 'Profile updated.';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Could not update profile. Please try again later.';
    }
}
```

And here is a fragment from the program which is supposed to utilise the function:

```
$array = array("$password", "$email", "$age");
                        if($array[0] != 0){
                            sql("password",$password);
                        }
                        if($array[1] != 0){
                            sql("email",$email);
                        }
                        if($array[2] != 0){
                            sql("age",$age);
                        }
```

It doesn't write the values to the database. What's wrong? Maybe it's the quotation of the variables in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quote on the `SET` :

```
function sql($set,$data){
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET ".$set." = '".$data."' WHERE login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'");
    if($sql){
        echo 'Profile updated.';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Could not update profile. Please try again later.';
    }
}
```

Column names don't dont need to be quoted

Working example here -> http://www.sqlize.com/c34I44c37r

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this. Now it only accepts and writes numerical values, it doesn't work with anything other than numbers.

Comment: I think you need to start reading some basic how-to's for MySQL / PHP -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: @user1020567 Describe is a mysql function - the output will show your table definition - if you followed my example above to the letter something else must be wrong (ie you have a numeric column)

Comment: that looks OK - apart from age being a varchar - should store numeric values in a number field ... have you copy/pasted my code above ? does it work ?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I've mistaken that for something else entirely. My table rows have a varchar datatype, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Which code? The one you posted in the answer? Yes, I've tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: It STILL does not work. I'm out of ideas, really... Here's my query:
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET ".$set." = '".$data."' WHERE login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'");

Comment: OK - 1) echo / log each of the valables to ensure they are correct 2) create the statement in a variable first then echo that to ensure it looks correct 3) try executing the statement in MySQL workbench or equivalent 4) show the errors you are getting when executing the statment

Comment: Not sure how to do the 2nd step.
By the way, the problem is that it will only accept integers - no other characters.

Comment: Woops, I just noticed that the password field also accepts letters. But the email and age fields do not - only integers. However I still can't use both letters and numbers in the password field.

Comment: The problem is the other function `if($array[0] != 0)` is the problem .... try `if($array[0])` instead

Comment: you where checking for a numeric value not testing for a value

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the quotation. To be specific, it's the quotation for the filed name (name, email, ..)

Just ` instead of '

> SET `foo` = 'bar'

PS: Please make sure that you escape the user input before writing it to db using `mysql_real_escape_string($data)`. Otherwise one could alter your query, which is called mysql injection.

Comment: No. You need to keep the string quotation on the VALUE part.. (here the word 'bar'.

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET `$set` = '$data' WHERE login = '".$_SESSION['login']."'");
Doesn't work

Comment: I know about SQL injection, however, at the moment I need only the fundamentals working.